# RavenDB MoreLikeThis with dynamic document - example?

Tags: ravendb

According to the [docs](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/server/bundles/more-like-this), RavenDB v3.5 added "MoreLikeThis" support for artificial documents, meaning that you can use a dynamic document for comparison instead of an already stored document.

I can't find an example of how this is done. The examples in the docs all seem to use existing documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that by passing the JSON string of the artificial document here:

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.5/Raven.Abstractions/Data/MoreLikeThisQuery.cs#L113

See the sample here: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/f3b5f3a186d07776bf38bf9effab4d7d75d5c647/Raven.Tests.Bundles/MoreLikeThis/MoreLikeThisShouldSupportMapReduceIndexes.cs#L100

```
        [Fact]
        public void CanMakeDynamicDocumentQueries()
        {
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var list = session.Advanced.MoreLikeThis<IndexDocument, MapReduceIndex>(
                    new MoreLikeThisQuery
                    {
                        Document = "{ \"Text\": \"C#: The Good Good Parts\" }",
                        Fields = new[] { "Text" },
                        MinimumTermFrequency = 1,
                        MinimumDocumentFrequency = 1
                    });

                Assert.Equal(2, list.Count());
                Assert.Contains("Javascript: The Good Parts", list.First().Text);
            }
        }
```